# Length Minimizing Properties of Geodesics on Surfaces?

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Can anyone recommend me some nice references about lengh minimizing properties of geodesics?

I'm looking for a treatment in the case of surfaces, but more general viewpoints will also be welcome.

More precisely I'd like to find a clear proof of the following fact:

**Theorem:** For each point $q$ in a normal neighbourhood of a given point $q$ the radial segment from $p$ to $q$ uniquely minimizes arc length.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

M. do Carmo "Riemannian Geometry", Chapter 3.